Are there any other German words related to "Fazit" other than its plural (and the like)?
B1 student here, and the word "Fazit" perplexes me. It comes from the Latin (facit) I've read, but I am not aware of other German words that share that etymology. Can anyone help?

I am not sure I understand the question. Are you asking for words which were directly taken from Latin into German? There are a lot of Latinisms in German, for instance Plazet (from placere), or Plakat (from placare). Another one is Veto. My Grandpa once wanted to convince me that Medikamente (the plural of Medikament) was an imperative of medicare with an ablative of mens, so something along the lines of "Cure with Reason", but that was an etymology he just made up. :D

There are indeed probably hundreds of words in German derived from Latin but I am not sure if that is your question or if you are asking for words derived from a finite Latin verb form, like Fazit and those mentioned in Jonathan Herrera's comment. Please clarify.

Even if you were asking about words derived from facere specifically, there would be a wide selection: Fakt(um), Faktor, Faktur(a), all with related verbs. As a composite, there is also Faksimile.

Wiktionary has a Category:German terms derived from Latin along with various subcategories; suffice to say there are hundreds of German words of Latin origin. As a learner you're less likely to encounter these words in German than you would in English. English imported many words from Norman French, which were in turn derived from Latin. And English was more likely to coin new words from Latin and Greek roots than German, which often created new word from home-grown German roots. A typical example is "television", from Latin and Greek, vs. "Fernsehen", from German roots. But don't get the impression that German existed in complete isolation. Latin words were spread over most of Europe through the influence of the Romans, and Latin was the language of the Catholic church as well as scientific discourse long after the Romans. Latin was used as a lingua franca in Europe for many centuries, so if you wanted to be understood you used a word from Latin instead of coining your own from whatever local dialect you happened to speak. Then there's the fact that Europe has a long history of trade and conquest between people speaking different languages, which led to the blurring of linguistic boundaries. The upshot is that most European languages, including German, have their share of words derived from Latin.
For what it's worth, the Etymology in DWDS says that "Fazit" made it's way into German sometime in the 14th century, basically as accounting jargon. I think that tracks since the 14th century was part of the lingua franca period for Latin, so if you had to invent a new term for some accounting concept you'd get it from Latin.
